# Making IE 11 Combo Box Look Like Chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-11

How can I get IE11 to use combo boxes as chrome does, is there a CSS fix to sort this out?

[image: IE vs Chrome Combobox picture]

I wish for the combobox to drop down as it does in Chrome, instead of move up as it does in IE

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking code help must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**.  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

This is standard Windows behaviour for ComboBox controls, now. I guess there are a couple things you can try:

- Down-grading your version of IE
- Down-grading your version of Windows (and not installing IE11 on the old version)
- Telling your browser to use an older version of its rendering engine:
  `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8" />`
- Writing your own custom combobox.

Other than what's mentioned above, I can't think of any way around this.

---

Edit:
I don't know what your client would accept, but since I highly doubt you'll be able to get your desired result, may I suggest using a custom combobox control, so at-least it will look the same in all browsers:
http://codepen.io/amyth91/pen/kHDwL

There are plenty of other ones to be found on Google.

Comment: I cannot downgrade the IE version this is part of ratification for IE11, and our client does not want to use compatibility mode

Comment: Paul, may I ask why your client wants to change the default behaviour of standard Windows controls? Doing such things usually leads to more user complaints. Remember those old custom scrollbars years ago? Many of them were a huge pain in the ass.

Comment: I am not 100% sure but they want the pages exactly the same as they are in IE7

Comment: I also have a problem with this, when setting compatibility mode with IE7 in the web page and browsing it with IE11 (in IE7 compatibility mode) is you click a combobox, it opens and you see the opcions, if when it is opened you click outside it, it collapses, loses the focus but it keeps the blue color, you can now click on another combobox, open it and click outside it, having this way 2 blue comboboxes. You can do it as many times as you want. Do you guys know of any fix for this too?